# Android: Using a Custom ArrayAdapter that implements OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

I am making a simple bus schedule application. I want to have two activities: 1st: a `ListView` of bus routes, and 2nd: a `ListView` of the departure times (BusRouteDetail) of each bus route. Essentially, I want to fill the BusRouteDetail `ListView`(2nd Activity) with different `arrays` of times based on which row in the Bus Route `ListView` (1st Activity) is clicked. I am trying to do this without making a separate `activity` for each bus route. Any ideas how to do this? I have tried using `convertView()`, `getView()`, and even using a `ListView` `Custom ArrayAdapter`to accomplish this with no luck.

Here is my Bus Route Code (1st Activity):

```
public class BusRoutes extends Activity {

final String[] busroutes = {"Bus Route 1, Bus Route 2, Bus Route 3, Bus Route 4, Bus Route 5" +
        "Bus Route 6", "Bus Route 7", "Bus Route 8", "Bus Route 9", "Bus Route 10"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus_routes);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    ListView busroutelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBusRoutes);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, busroutes);
    busroutelist.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    busroutelist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String busroute = busroutes[position];
            String[] mondayfridayhrs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mondayfridayhrs);
            String[] saturdayhrs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.saturdayhrs);
            final String mondayfridayhours = mondayfridayhrs[position];
            final String saturdayhours = saturdayhrs[position];

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BusRouteDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("busroute", busroute);
            intent.putExtra("mondayfridayhours", mondayfridayhours);
            intent.putExtra("saturdayhours", saturdayhours);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

Here is my BusRouteDetail Code (2nd Activity):

```
public class BusRouteDetails extends Activity {

String mondayfridayhrs;
String saturdayhrs;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus_route_details);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    TextView tvMf = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMf);
    TextView tvSat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSat);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null){

        mondayfridayhrs = extras.getString("mondayfridayhours");
        tvMf.setText(mondayfridayhrs);

        saturdayhrs = extras.getString("saturdayhours");
        tvSat.setText(saturdayhrs);
    }

    final String[] firsttest = {"Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5",
        "Test 6", "Test 7", "Test 8", "Test 9", "Test 10", "Test 11", "Test 12",
        "Test 13", "Test 14", "Test 15", "Test 16", "Test 17", "Test 18", "Test 19", "Test 20"
    };

    final String[] secondtest = {"2nd Test 1", "2nd Test 2", "2nd Test 3", "2nd Test 4", "2nd Test 5",
         "2nd Test 6", "2nd Test 7", "2nd Test 8", "2nd Test 9", "2nd Test 10", "2nd Test 11", "2nd Test 12",
         "2nd Test 13", "2nd Test 14", "2nd Test 15", "2nd Test 16", "2nd Test 17", "2nd Test 18",
         "2nd Test 19", "2nd Test 20"
    };

    final String[] thirdtest = {"3rd Test 1", "3rd Test 2", "3rd Test 3", "3rd Test 4", "3rd Test 5",
            "3rd Test 6", "3rd Test 7", "3rd Test 8", "3rd Test 9", "3rd Test 10", "3rd Test 11", "3rd Test 12",
            "3rd Test 13", "3rd Test 14", "3rd Test 15", "3rd Test 16", "3rd Test 17", "3rd Test 18",
            "3rd Test 19", "3rd Test 20"
    };

    final ListView detaillist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBusRouteDetails);

    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewtextview, firsttest);
    detaillist.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    detaillist.setOnItemClickListener(null);
}}
```

Comment: dont you think that such data should be stored in an sqlite database and instead of `ArrayAdapter` a `SimpleCursorAdapter` should be used?

Comment: I am a beginner with android app development and am not that familiar with SQLite Database. Can I use the `CursorAdapter` to retrieve data stored in the sqlite database? I know I need a Field, Type and Key in the database. Would I simply enter the departure times in the Field column?

Comment: yes, `CursorAdapter` is used by a `ListView` to show `Cursor` data

Comment: google for `SimpleCursorAdapter` the first non `developer.android.com/...` link is: https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: What I'm wondering is, every example I've seen is a database with at least 3-4 different columns of data. I only have one, which would be the hours of departure for each bus route. Would a SQLite Database work for me/is it necessary?

Comment: now it is "hours of departure", tomorrow you will have "the disabled friendly" field or "free wifi" or whatever, BTW now you gotta have: line_number + departure_time + (optionally: the days in the week it works)

Comment: What do you mean be "free wifi"? Also. The "line number" will not be visible, correct? It is only a way of referencing the line so I can populate the ListView with  the correct table? Will I have to create a separate table for each bus route?

Comment: `Will I have to create a separate table for each bus route? ` of course not, that's why i said that in your table you gotta have at least two/three fields: lineNo, departureTime and daysItOperates

Comment: So my fields could be: bus1hours, bus2hours, bus3hours,etc. and then with CursorAdapter I can set the ListView of the second activity to the field that I specify based on what row I click?

Comment: no, you will have 3 fields (columns) and many many rows

Comment: In the second ListView all I want are hours and destination to be displayed in one line. That would mean I only have two fields, lineNo and departure time? I want it in the format that each row in the second ListView says, in one line, leaving from "destination" @ "time"

Comment: ok so this is the table you need: `create table routes (route_no TEXT, departure_time TEXT, service_days TEXT);`

Comment: Ok sweet I understand that, I have that created in a separate Java class. Line_no refers to the line number in the bus route ListView, correct?

Comment: yes i could name it `route_number`, in short it is `route_no`

Comment: Perfect. Do I have to set an onclicklistener for the rows in the first ListView? Or will the CursorAdapter do that for me?

Comment: you have to setup `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: Can you please provide me with some sample code? I can't visualize this. Nothing on the internet seems to pertain to what I am trying to do. I really appreciate the time you have spent with me.

Comment: i already gave a link on how to use a `SCA`

Comment: That didn't help me with populating a ListView with data from an onitemclicklistener in another ListView

Comment: so inside `onitemclicklistener` start a second activity and pass the `route_no` via intent extras

Comment: In total, I would pass the `route_no` and the `departure_times` right? I don't need the `service_days`, I only want the departure times to fill the ListView.

Comment: pass `route_no` only and make a query in a new activity based on `route_no`

Comment: Would it be an `if-statement` in the second activity to determine which set of `departure_times` to fill the `route_no` ListView with?

Comment: what set do you mean?

Comment: sorry. By set I meant "field".

Comment: sorry. I have no green idea what you mean

Comment: I'm so lost. There is no code for this and it's frustrating. Would you be able to tell me how to fully accomplish this in detail and then I can do the rest.

Comment: There has to be an easier way than using a SQLite Database

Comment: just pass `route_no` to the new activity and use it as a parameter to a sql query, do some reasearch on sqlite on android, do something, dont wait for anyone, be active

Comment: From what I'm understanding. I must populate the first ListView from SQLite, and then when I click one of the rows, populate the second ListView according to the row_no that was clicked?

Comment: you have to populate the second ListView according to the `route_no` that was clicked

Comment: Okay. Thank you, I think I'm going to try a different way. I can't figure this out at all.